# PyCharm program for showing year of birth

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am looking to write a program in python that would print "Hello" user_name ! "you were born in" birth_year "." I have the code that would produce this, but I am getting a space in the output and I can't figure out why/how to remove it.

Code is here:
from datetime import date

```
# ask user for input here
 user_name = input('What is your name?')
 user_age = int(input('What is your age?'))
 current_yr = date.today().year

# calculation for birth year from user input
birth_year = (current_yr - user_age)

# print output from user
print('Hello', user_name, "!", 'You were born in', birth_year, ".")
```

That is my code there. I need the output to look like this :

Hello John! You were born in 1992.

I keep getting this instead: Hello John ! You were born in 1992 .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use f-string:

> print(f'Hello{user_name}! You were born in {birth_year}.')

Comment: Awesome! thank you. I couldn't figure it out for the life of me. I didn't realize it auto adds the space in there.

Answer (score 0):

Print function in Python separates each argument with a space by default, so in

```py
print('Hello', user_name, "!", 'You were born in', birth_year, ".")
```

everywhere where you have a coma, there will be a space in the resulting string. There are two approaches to solve this:

- You can change the separator by adding additional `sep=''` argument (it'll make `print` separate arguments with nothing), but you'll have to manually add spaces where necessary:

```py
print('Hello ', user_name, "!", ' You were born in ', birth_year, ".", sep='')
# or even shorter:
print('Hello ', user_name, '! You were born in ', birth_year, '.', sep='')
```

- You can use formatted strings (as suggested by Toshio):

```py
print(f'Hello{user_name}! You were born in {birth_year}.')
```

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you for showing two different options. I'll keep in mind the auto spacing for future use.